# How to get a string[] from the following JSON string?

Tags: java

I have the following string

```
["xyz@live.com","abc@live.com"]
```

I am using `String.split(",")` to get String[]. But array contents consist of '[' and '"'.

I need to get the actual strings with out quotes. Is there a library or method with which I can do it?

At present I am doing like this.

```
    recipients = recipients.replace("\"", "");
    recipients = recipients.replace("[", "");
    recipients = recipients.replace("]", "");
    String[] totalRecipients = recipients.split(",");
```

Comment: Why don't you try to parse the JSON string instead of trying to do string manipulations on it? You'll get a `List<String>` on parsing that JSON String which can be easily converted to an array of Strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De-serialize the json string to java object using `boon` or `jackson` 3rd party library.

Boon Example -

```
ObjectMapper mapper =  JsonFactory.create();
String[] recipientArray = mapper.readValue(recipients , String[].class, String.class);
```

Find Java Boon vs jackson json - Benchmarks - [here](https://github.com/RichardHightower/json-parsers-benchmark)

[image]

Source : [Link](https://github.com/RichardHightower/json-parsers-benchmark)

Comment: This bar chart is not really helpful. What does it try to say? That Jackson is 25% as fast as Boon? Or that Jackson needs just 25ms for something where Boon needs around 100ms?

Comment: it is throughput graph vertical axis says troughput. Get better understanding from the link resource.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder Thank you. My project is already using net.sf.json library. I didn't find which methods I could use from the same.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use json library to solve it.

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

```
String s = "[\"xyz@live.com\",\"abc@live.com\"]";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(s);
for(JsonNode n : node){
 .......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use of [google's gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and to decode your json to `String[]` you can simply use this line of code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] myArray =  gson.fromJson(yourjson,String[].class);
```